# Trying to run a program from appdata\local but it crashes

Tags: vb.net

You helped me write my first VB program a while back, the code is below and it works fine, ive written a bunch of small programs using this as code.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim usernamepath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
        Dim thefolder = usernamepath + "\AIOFLASH\p2vflash"
        Dim startInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(thefolder & "\P2v.exe")
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = usernamepath + "\AIOFLASH\p2vflash"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo)#
```

I now want to move the storage folder (userprofile) to Appdata\local then the folder but if i change it to the code below and I press the button it throws up an exception error with file not found.
I have all the needed files in the correct folders etc

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim usernamepath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
        Dim thefolder = usernamepath + "\AIOFLASH\p2vflash"
        Dim startInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(thefolder & "\P2v.exe")
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = usernamepath + "\AIOFLASH\p2vflash"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Does using the localapplicationdata need some other type of code?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Since it looks like you have a WinForms app, why don't you use `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` ? You always have the *correct rights* there. Or `Application.CommonAppDataPath`. BTW, use `Path.Combine()` to build paths. -- You should use `&` to concatenate strings, not `+`. -- Does `AIOFLASH\p2vflash` exist? Is it part of the directory structure of your Project?

Comment: Ok be aware that I am really new to this, the code was suggested by another user, I will take a look at using your suggestions, yes aioflash\p2vflash does exist, I use AIOFllash as a folder to store the other folders that each contain a seperate VB project. I will get back to you soon and let you know, many thanks

Comment: @Jimi What's wrong with using "+" for concatenation? It's supported. Personally, I now use the `$"A string with a {variable}"` form where appropriate as it's more succinct and auto-converts types to string. Nice.

Comment: The `+` operator *can* be used to concatenate strings, but, with `Option Strict` set to `OFF` (as it is, unfortunately, for many new VB.Net programmers or *amateurs* - and some not so new, very unfortunately), it can have unpredictable results. The intended *aggregator* is the `&` operator. It works in any case the same. -- What you use now is called String Interpolation. It's used most of the time today. It's `String.Format()` in another *vest*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify directly the working directory

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim usernamepath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
    Dim thefolder = usernamepath + "\AIOFLASH\p2vflash"
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(thefolder & "\P2v.exe",thefolder)
```